# djnago application cant see data from html

Tags: html, django

I have django application named emnosy (emergency notification system)
when i try to use add_contact function from html
i can see only that error

```
IntegrityError at /addcontact/
ERROR: A null value in the "message" column violates the NOT NULL constraint
DETAIL: The error line contains (2, booby, null, booby@gmail.com).
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/addcontact/
Django Version: 3.2.23
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:
ERROR: A null value in the "message" column violates the NOT NULL constraint
DETAIL: The error line contains (2, booby, null, booby@gmail.com).
Exception Location: D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable: D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.9
Python Path:
['D:\\projects\\EmNoSy\\venv\\emnosys_wqrfl',
  'C:\\Program'
  'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python37.zip',
  'C:\\Program'
  'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs',
  'C:\\Program'
  'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib',
  'C:\\Program'
  'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0',
  'D:\\projects\\EmNoSy\\venv',
  'D:\\projects\\EmNoSy\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time: Thu, 23 Nov 2023 15:50:47 +0000
```

i dont know how to fix that issue

this is my addcontacts.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/emnosys/css/addcontacts.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="about">
        <div class="label">
            Add contact
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="username">
                <input name="about--username" id="about--username" placeholder=" " maxlength="40"></input>
                <label for="#about--username" id="username--label">Username for recipient (locally)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="textarea">
                <textarea name="about--textarea" id="about--textarea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder=" " maxlength="999"></textarea>
                <label for="#about--textarea" id="textarea--label">Message</label>
            </div>
            <div class="telegram" id="telegram--label">
                <input name="about--email" id="about--email" placeholder=" " maxlength="40"></input>
                <label for="#about--email" id="email--label">Email of recipient (for example "qwerty@gmail.com")</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="waves">
        <img src="../../static/emnosys/images/waves.png" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Contact


####################################################

class Main(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'emnosys/main.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_file'] = 'styles.css'
        return context

###################################################



def Registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password1)
        myuser.save()

        return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, "emnosys/registration.html")

###############################################

def Signin(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['pass1']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "emnosys/main.html")
        else:
            return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, "emnosys/signin.html")

################################################

def Signout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

######################################################

class PersonalPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'emnosys/personalpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_file'] = 'styles.css'
        return context

####################################################


def add_contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('about--username')
        message = request.POST.get('about--message')
        email = request.POST.get('about--email')
        Contact.objects.create(username=username, message=message, email=email)
    return render(request, 'emnosys/addcontacts.html')
```

this is my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class Contact(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    message = models.TextField(null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=99, null=False)
```

i have know ideas how to fix that, but i know that problem is in textarea (in html)

i will be very grateful if someone know how to solve this issue

Comment: You have column message that `null=False` so it cannot be empty

Comment: Its not empty, i wrote data to ''textarea'' in html and i can see only that error(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` attribute from your textarea is `about--textarea` and you try to retrieve it in your add contact function with `request.POST.get('about--message')`. You have to choose the same name.